# How do I remove all "edges" from a node?

Tags: java, arrays, nodes, adjacency-matrix

A question for my comp sci class goes like this:

> We can represent a graph using an "adjacency matrix" `int[][] matrix`. `matrix[i][j]` will be non-zero if there is an edge FROM node i TO node j. In other words, node i considers node j to be its "neighbor" in this case. Note that this does not necessarily mean node j considers node i to be ITS neighbor, allowing for asymmetrical relationships. Each value could also be zero, indicating there is no edge/connection. The matrix will be n x n in size, where n is the number of nodes and nodes are numbered 0 to n-1, allowing any node to connect to any other node numbered within this range.

> Given an adjacency matrix and `int x`, remove all edges to and from the node at index x.

I understand what an adjacency matrix is, but I don't understand what the problem means by edges, or what index x is.

My code so far looks like this:

```
public void removeEdgesFromNode(int[][] matrix, int x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        
        
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[].length; j++) {
            if(j == x || i == x) {
                matrix[i, j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

There is an error occurring where it says

```
Compilation error on line 7: error: class expected
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[].length; j++) {
                                    ^
```

I don't think the way I'm solving the problem is correct, however I am attempting to start the problem at least.

Comment: `j < matrix[].length` -> `j < matrix[0].length`

Comment: You don't need to nest loops.  Just have a single loop that clears `matrix[i][x]` and `matrix[x][i]` where `i` is the index of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution. Because you have a square *n x n* matrix and fixed an index `x` in the range *0 .. n - 1* you want to remove all elements staying in the xth row or in the xth column you can do it with one loop like below:

```
public static void removeEdgesFromNode(int[][] matrix, int x) {
    int n = matrix.length;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        matrix[i][x] = 0;
        matrix[x][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

If you use an `x` index equal or greater than *n* an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception will be thrown, it's up to you decide how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are solving the problem is correct, but not the most optimal.
The edges from x, would mean that matrix[x][j] would be 0 for each j.
The edges to x, would mean that matrix[i][x] would be 0 for each i.
In other words, all the elements matrix[i][j] where i or j are x, should be 0. Which is what you are doing.

First things first. Your error. `matrix[].length` should be `matrix.length`. Try your solution. It should work.

For the most optimal solution check Dariosicily answer. However with that one you need to make sure that the matrix is squared and `x<n`.

Your answer would go over every element of the matrix, so `nxn= n^2` elements with complexity `O(n^2)`, but his solution you only need to go over `2*n` elements `O(n)`, so when n is very big, you would notice the performance improvement. You can give it a try :)